# Isomorphism of chain complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

In my notes it says $C^{sing}_n(\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i;R) \cong {\bigoplus}_{i \in I} C^{sing}_n(X_i;R)$, where $C^{sing}_n$ denotes the n-th singular chain complex and $R$ is a ring, $S_n(X)$ is the set of all continuous maps $\sigma: {\Delta}_n \to X$ and ${\Delta}_n$ is the standard n-simplex. It is quite obvious that $S_n(\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i) = \sqcup_{i\in I}S_n(X_i)$, since the maps are continuous.

But if I take an element $ c \in C^{sing}_n(\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i)$, then I can write $c = {\sum}_{\sigma \in S_n(\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i)} {\lambda}_{\sigma} \sigma , {\lambda}_{\sigma} \in R$ and then $c = {\sum}_{\sigma \in S_n(\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i)} {\lambda}_{\sigma} \sigma = {\sum}_{\sigma \in \sqcup_{i\in I}S_n(X_i)} {\lambda}_{\sigma} \sigma = {\sum}_{i \in I}{\sum}_{\sigma \in S_n(X_i)} {\lambda}_{\sigma} \sigma \in {\bigoplus}_{i \in I} C^{sing}_n(X_i;R)$. So this would suggest $C^{sing}_n(\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i;R) = {\bigoplus}_{i \in I} C^{sing}_n(X_i;R)$.

Where am I wrong? What is the explicit isomorphism (and why is it an isomorphism)?

Comment: I'm confused--why do you think you have gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: Because I came to the conclusion that the mentioned chain complexes are the same and not just isomorphic, i.e. not isomorphic via the identity.

Comment: @Cosmare, the statement is that one $R$-module is isomorphic to the sum of another $R$-modules. When you take cochains, for example, you can only construct such map (inverse directed), that will be _not_ isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether these chain complexes are literally equal depends on the precise set-theoretic definitions you have chosen for all the notation involved.  For instance, a common definition of ${\bigoplus}_{i \in I} C^{sing}_n(X_i;R)$ is the set of all functions $f$ with domain $I$ such that $f(i)\in C^{sing}_n(X_i;R)$ for each $i\in I$ and $f(i)$ is the zero element of $C^{sing}_n(X_i;R)$ for all but finitely many values of $i$.  Such a function is not an element of the set $C^{sing}_n(\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i;R)$.  Also, $S_n(\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i) = \sqcup_{i\in I}S_n(X_i)$ is not true for the usual definition of $\sqcup$ (which says something like $\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i=\bigcup_{i\in I} \{i\}\times X_i$).

In any case, worrying about these exact set-theoretic definitions is missing the point.  We don't actually care exactly what set the notation ${\bigoplus}_{i \in I} C^{sing}_n(X_i;R)$ refers to, we only care about certain properties it has which characterize it up to canonical isomorphism.  The correspondence between elements of ${\bigoplus}_{i \in I} C^{sing}_n(X_i;R)$ and elements $C^{sing}_n(\sqcup_{i\in I} X_i;R)$ which you have written down is an isomorphism, and that is what matters.  Maybe for some choices of the set-theoretic definitions involved your correspondence is actually literally the identity, but that doesn't really make a difference for anything you might want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a mistake in in one of your formulas: $S_n(\amalg_{i\in I} X_i)\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I} S_n(X_i)$ and not disjoint union. Also, the two chain complexes you are interested in can't be *exactly* equal since the left hand side consists of linear combinations of chains, whereas the right hand side consists of $I$-tuplets of linear combinations of chains. The isomorphism between them is morally close to the identity though.

Comment: I think the singular chains of a disjoint union is actually the direct sum of the singular chains of each component, not the product, in general. No?